# Cleaning a dirty JSON and outputting a clean version with the English, the translation and the type of data in the right order

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am writing an api which takes in a JSON as input and outputs a pretty version of it. The dirty JSON which is inputted are script notes from a TV broadcast. As such, there is a type of data e.g "OOV" or "PIX", an English script, and a translated version in Persian.

1. One issue which I am having trouble with is that some English translations into Persian take up multiple indexes in the son array - so I am having trouble keeping the right translations together with the right English script.
2. I am also having trouble working out how to loop through the array and add it to a JSON object to output and store the right information only at times when the information is new inside the loop. i.e there are lots of duplicates. My tactic, presented below may be the wrong way about doing this altogether but I am having coder's block with it right now so any advice would be helpful!
3. Also I keep getting an error " "message": "Unexpected token چ in JSON at position 247""... This is just a Persian word, I'm not sure why this particular symbol is not allowed when all the others are...

```js
function parseJson(json) {

    let meta = "";
    let english = "";
    let persian = "";
    let jsonRemovedNull = [json.length];
    let intCounter = 0;
    json.forEach((text) => {
        if (text != '') {
            jsonRemovedNull[intCounter] = text;
            intCounter++;
        }
    });
    console.log(jsonRemovedNull);

    var obj = [json.length];

    for (let i = 0; i < jsonRemovedNull.length - 3; i++) {

        if (jsonRemovedNull[i].substring(0, 3) === "OOV" || jsonRemovedNull[i].substring(0, 3) === "PTC" || jsonRemovedNull[i].substring(0, 3) === "PIX" || jsonRemovedNull[i].substring(0, 4) === "SPEN") {
            meta = jsonRemovedNull[i];

        }
        else if (jsonRemovedNull[i].charAt(0).match(/[^a-z,A-Z, ,.,:,-,’,!,”,“,-,0-9,-,-]/gm)) {
            persian = jsonRemovedNull[i];

        }
        else if (jsonRemovedNull[i].charAt(0).match(/[a-z,A-Z, 0-9,]/gm) && !jsonRemovedNull[i + 2].includes("OOV") && !jsonRemovedNull[i + 2].includes("PTC") && !jsonRemovedNull[i + 2].includes("PIX")) {
            english = jsonRemovedNull[i];

        }
        if (meta != null) {
            obj[i] = JSON.parse(`{ "Meta": "${meta}","English": "${english}", "Persian": "${persian}" }`)
        }
        if (persian != null) {
            obj[i] = JSON.parse(`{ "Meta": "${meta}","English": "${english}", "Persian": "${persian}" }`)
        }
        if (english != null) {
            obj[i] = JSON.parse(`{ "Meta": "${meta}","English": "${english}", "Persian": "${persian}" }`)
        }

       obj[i] = JSON.parse(`{ "Meta": "${meta}","English": "${english}", "Persian": "${persian}" }`);

    }



    return obj;

}

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const entireData = req.body;
    const extractedData = parseJson(entireData);
   
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Handling POST requests to /products',
        script: extractedData
    });
});
```

Output:

1. If looping through every element in the json array i.e i++ in the for loop:

   {
       "error": {
           "message": "Unexpected token چ in JSON at position 247"
       }
   }
2. If looping through only eery other element in the son array i.e I=I+2 (see below)

```js
  {
            "message": "Handling POST requests to /products",
            "script": [
                {
                    "Meta": "",
                    "English": "",
                    "Persian": "FARSI 975 CES 2019 "
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX - CES",
                    "English": "",
                    "Persian": "FARSI 975 CES 2019 "
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX - CES",
                    "English": "2019 starts with the Consumer Electronics Show in Las Vegas",
                    "Persian": "FARSI 975 CES 2019 "
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX - CES",
                    "English": "2019 starts with the Consumer Electronics Show in Las Vegas",
                    "Persian": "سال ۲۰۱۹ با نمایشگاه بین‌المللی سی ای اس در لاس‌وگاس آغاز شد"
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX - CES",
                    "English": "2019 starts with the Consumer Electronics Show in Las Vegas",
                    "Persian": "و هر چه که توجه‌ها رو به خودش جلب کنه... چیزی که اصلا ماهیت وگاسه."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX - CES",
                    "English": "2019 starts with the Consumer Electronics Show in Las Vegas",
                    "Persian": "و هر چه که توجه‌ها رو به خودش جلب کنه... چیزی که اصلا ماهیت وگاسه."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "2019 starts with the Consumer Electronics Show in Las Vegas",
                    "Persian": "و هر چه که توجه‌ها رو به خودش جلب کنه... چیزی که اصلا ماهیت وگاسه."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "2019 starts with the Consumer Electronics Show in Las Vegas",
                    "Persian": "ما تلاش می کنیم چند و چون نمایشگاه سی ای اس 2019 را با شما در میان بذاریم با...             "
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "2019 starts with the Consumer Electronics Show in Las Vegas",
                    "Persian": "ما تلاش می کنیم چند و چون نمایشگاه سی ای اس 2019 را با شما در میان بذاریم با...             "
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "2019 starts with the Consumer Electronics Show in Las Vegas",
                    "Persian": "بیست تکه فناوری در 19 دقیقه. دقت کنید که این چیزای خیلی زیادیه در وقت خیلی کم."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "GFX - REWIND THE COUNTERS FROM 20 TO 0 AND FROM 19 TO 0",
                    "Persian": "بیست تکه فناوری در 19 دقیقه. دقت کنید که این چیزای خیلی زیادیه در وقت خیلی کم."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "So, reset the counter, reset the clock - and we’ll start with something that’s always big here - TVs…",
                    "Persian": "بیست تکه فناوری در 19 دقیقه. دقت کنید که این چیزای خیلی زیادیه در وقت خیلی کم."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "SPEN / GADGET 1 / OLED LG TV",
                    "English": "So, reset the counter, reset the clock - and we’ll start with something that’s always big here - TVs…",
                    "Persian": "بیست تکه فناوری در 19 دقیقه. دقت کنید که این چیزای خیلی زیادیه در وقت خیلی کم."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "OOV:",
                    "English": "So, reset the counter, reset the clock - and we’ll start with something that’s always big here - TVs…",
                    "Persian": "بیست تکه فناوری در 19 دقیقه. دقت کنید که این چیزای خیلی زیادیه در وقت خیلی کم."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "OOV:",
                    "English": "So, reset the counter, reset the clock - and we’ll start with something that’s always big here - TVs…",
                    "Persian": "فناوری بزرگ نمایشگر در اینجا او لده، و ال‌جی دیسپلی تنها شرکتیه که نمایشگرهای بزرگ او-لد می‌سازه. فناوری‌ای که چندین قابلیت داره. می‌تونه قوس برداره، می‌تونه سیاهش واقعا سیاه سیاه باشه..."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "OOV:",
                    "English": "So, reset the counter, reset the clock - and we’ll start with something that’s always big here - TVs…",
                    "Persian": "فناوری بزرگ نمایشگر در اینجا او لده، و ال‌جی دیسپلی تنها شرکتیه که نمایشگرهای بزرگ او-لد می‌سازه. فناوری‌ای که چندین قابلیت داره. می‌تونه قوس برداره، می‌تونه سیاهش واقعا سیاه سیاه باشه..."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "OOV:",
                    "English": "So, reset the counter, reset the clock - and we’ll start with something that’s always big here - TVs…",
                    "Persian": "یا حتی شفاف بشه؟"
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "OOV:",
                    "English": "So, reset the counter, reset the clock - and we’ll start with something that’s always big here - TVs…",
                    "Persian": "یا حتی شفاف بشه؟"
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "OOV:",
                    "English": "So, reset the counter, reset the clock - and we’ll start with something that’s always big here - TVs…",
                    "Persian": "می‌تونه بسیار نازک... و البته می‌تونه با کیفیت 8K باشه. یعنی چهار برابر وضوح بیشتر از 4k."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "OOV:",
                    "English": "So, reset the counter, reset the clock - and we’ll start with something that’s always big here - TVs…",
                    "Persian": "می‌تونه بسیار نازک... و البته می‌تونه با کیفیت 8K باشه. یعنی چهار برابر وضوح بیشتر از 4k."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX - CLOSE UP OF BENDY PHONE, THEN CLOSE-UP OF HANDBAG AND TOP HAT WITH SCREENS ON, NOT REVEALING THAT SPEN IS WEARING THEM",
                    "English": "So, reset the counter, reset the clock - and we’ll start with something that’s always big here - TVs…",
                    "Persian": "می‌تونه بسیار نازک... و البته می‌تونه با کیفیت 8K باشه. یعنی چهار برابر وضوح بیشتر از 4k."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX - CLOSE UP OF BENDY PHONE, THEN CLOSE-UP OF HANDBAG AND TOP HAT WITH SCREENS ON, NOT REVEALING THAT SPEN IS WEARING THEM",
                    "English": "And finally this year, we’ve seen actual practical uses of possibly OLED’s coolest feature - it can be bendy.",
                    "Persian": "می‌تونه بسیار نازک... و البته می‌تونه با کیفیت 8K باشه. یعنی چهار برابر وضوح بیشتر از 4k."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX - CLOSE UP OF BENDY PHONE, THEN CLOSE-UP OF HANDBAG AND TOP HAT WITH SCREENS ON, NOT REVEALING THAT SPEN IS WEARING THEM",
                    "English": "GFX: 1 - 2",
                    "Persian": "می‌تونه بسیار نازک... و البته می‌تونه با کیفیت 8K باشه. یعنی چهار برابر وضوح بیشتر از 4k."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX - CLOSE UP OF BENDY PHONE, THEN CLOSE-UP OF HANDBAG AND TOP HAT WITH SCREENS ON, NOT REVEALING THAT SPEN IS WEARING THEM",
                    "English": "GFX: 2 - 2",
                    "Persian": "می‌تونه بسیار نازک... و البته می‌تونه با کیفیت 8K باشه. یعنی چهار برابر وضوح بیشتر از 4k."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX - CLOSE UP OF BENDY PHONE, THEN CLOSE-UP OF HANDBAG AND TOP HAT WITH SCREENS ON, NOT REVEALING THAT SPEN IS WEARING THEM",
                    "English": "Well, if you’ve been meaning for a while to get round to having an eye test but have not quite had time, the solution could be this. (showing device attached to her phone) This device attaches to a smartphone and you can test your own eyes. Now, what you do is… you look through one eye at a time (Lara using device) There’s a green line and red line, and you need to move them closer together - You just tap this button on the top to do it… (Lara pressing the button) And...there we go, I hope I’m not going to learn anything surprising. ",
                    "Persian": "می‌تونه بسیار نازک... و البته می‌تونه با کیفیت 8K باشه. یعنی چهار برابر وضوح بیشتر از 4k."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX - CLOSE UP OF BENDY PHONE, THEN CLOSE-UP OF HANDBAG AND TOP HAT WITH SCREENS ON, NOT REVEALING THAT SPEN IS WEARING THEM",
                    "English": "Well, if you’ve been meaning for a while to get round to having an eye test but have not quite had time, the solution could be this. (showing device attached to her phone) This device attaches to a smartphone and you can test your own eyes. Now, what you do is… you look through one eye at a time (Lara using device) There’s a green line and red line, and you need to move them closer together - You just tap this button on the top to do it… (Lara pressing the button) And...there we go, I hope I’m not going to learn anything surprising. ",
                    "Persian": "می‌تونه بسیار نازک... و البته می‌تونه با کیفیت 8K باشه. یعنی چهار برابر وضوح بیشتر از 4k."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX- Nick entrance shot ",
                    "English": "Well, if you’ve been meaning for a while to get round to having an eye test but have not quite had time, the solution could be this. (showing device attached to her phone) This device attaches to a smartphone and you can test your own eyes. Now, what you do is… you look through one eye at a time (Lara using device) There’s a green line and red line, and you need to move them closer together - You just tap this button on the top to do it… (Lara pressing the button) And...there we go, I hope I’m not going to learn anything surprising. ",
                    "Persian": "می‌تونه بسیار نازک... و البته می‌تونه با کیفیت 8K باشه. یعنی چهار برابر وضوح بیشتر از 4k."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX- Nick entrance shot ",
                    "English": "Well, if you’ve been meaning for a while to get round to having an eye test but have not quite had time, the solution could be this. (showing device attached to her phone) This device attaches to a smartphone and you can test your own eyes. Now, what you do is… you look through one eye at a time (Lara using device) There’s a green line and red line, and you need to move them closer together - You just tap this button on the top to do it… (Lara pressing the button) And...there we go, I hope I’m not going to learn anything surprising. ",
                    "Persian": "می‌تونه بسیار نازک... و البته می‌تونه با کیفیت 8K باشه. یعنی چهار برابر وضوح بیشتر از 4k."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX - montage of Nick parking around exercising. ",
                    "English": "Well, if you’ve been meaning for a while to get round to having an eye test but have not quite had time, the solution could be this. (showing device attached to her phone) This device attaches to a smartphone and you can test your own eyes. Now, what you do is… you look through one eye at a time (Lara using device) There’s a green line and red line, and you need to move them closer together - You just tap this button on the top to do it… (Lara pressing the button) And...there we go, I hope I’m not going to learn anything surprising. ",
                    "Persian": "می‌تونه بسیار نازک... و البته می‌تونه با کیفیت 8K باشه. یعنی چهار برابر وضوح بیشتر از 4k."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX - montage of Nick parking around exercising. ",
                    "English": "So around this suit are various sensors that are analysing my motion and the idea is that they’ll be able to tell me if I’m using the correct posture or not when doing various exercises. So if I’m not doing my lunges correctly I’ll get me a ruddy good telling off!",
                    "Persian": "می‌تونه بسیار نازک... و البته می‌تونه با کیفیت 8K باشه. یعنی چهار برابر وضوح بیشتر از 4k."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PIX - montage of Nick parking around exercising. ",
                    "English": "So around this suit are various sensors that are analysing my motion and the idea is that they’ll be able to tell me if I’m using the correct posture or not when doing various exercises. So if I’m not doing my lunges correctly I’ll get me a ruddy good telling off!",
                    "Persian": "می‌تونه بسیار نازک... و البته می‌تونه با کیفیت 8K باشه. یعنی چهار برابر وضوح بیشتر از 4k."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "OOV:",
                    "English": "So around this suit are various sensors that are analysing my motion and the idea is that they’ll be able to tell me if I’m using the correct posture or not when doing various exercises. So if I’m not doing my lunges correctly I’ll get me a ruddy good telling off!",
                    "Persian": "می‌تونه بسیار نازک... و البته می‌تونه با کیفیت 8K باشه. یعنی چهار برابر وضوح بیشتر از 4k."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "OOV:",
                    "English": "So around this suit are various sensors that are analysing my motion and the idea is that they’ll be able to tell me if I’m using the correct posture or not when doing various exercises. So if I’m not doing my lunges correctly I’ll get me a ruddy good telling off!",
                    "Persian": "یک سری شتاب‌سنج، ژیروسکوپ یا چرخش‌نما و قطب‌نمای الکترونیکی، داخل لباس Racefit جاساز شدند که کارهایی رو که انجام می‌دم و چطوری انجام می‌دم رو اندازه‌گیری می‌کنند تا به یک اپ کمک کنند تا تنبیهم کنه."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "OOV:",
                    "English": "So around this suit are various sensors that are analysing my motion and the idea is that they’ll be able to tell me if I’m using the correct posture or not when doing various exercises. So if I’m not doing my lunges correctly I’ll get me a ruddy good telling off!",
                    "Persian": "یک سری شتاب‌سنج، ژیروسکوپ یا چرخش‌نما و قطب‌نمای الکترونیکی، داخل لباس Racefit جاساز شدند که کارهایی رو که انجام می‌دم و چطوری انجام می‌دم رو اندازه‌گیری می‌کنند تا به یک اپ کمک کنند تا تنبیهم کنه."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "OOV:",
                    "English": "So around this suit are various sensors that are analysing my motion and the idea is that they’ll be able to tell me if I’m using the correct posture or not when doing various exercises. So if I’m not doing my lunges correctly I’ll get me a ruddy good telling off!",
                    "Persian": "یک سری شتاب‌سنج، ژیروسکوپ یا چرخش‌نما و قطب‌نمای الکترونیکی، داخل لباس Racefit جاساز شدند که کارهایی رو که انجام می‌دم و چطوری انجام می‌دم رو اندازه‌گیری می‌کنند تا به یک اپ کمک کنند تا تنبیهم کنه."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "OOV:",
                    "English": "So around this suit are various sensors that are analysing my motion and the idea is that they’ll be able to tell me if I’m using the correct posture or not when doing various exercises. So if I’m not doing my lunges correctly I’ll get me a ruddy good telling off!",
                    "Persian": "باید به طور بی‌سیم شارژش کنید اما خوشبختانه می‌شه توی ماشین لباسشویی شستش."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "OOV:",
                    "English": "So around this suit are various sensors that are analysing my motion and the idea is that they’ll be able to tell me if I’m using the correct posture or not when doing various exercises. So if I’m not doing my lunges correctly I’ll get me a ruddy good telling off!",
                    "Persian": "باید به طور بی‌سیم شارژش کنید اما خوشبختانه می‌شه توی ماشین لباسشویی شستش."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "So around this suit are various sensors that are analysing my motion and the idea is that they’ll be able to tell me if I’m using the correct posture or not when doing various exercises. So if I’m not doing my lunges correctly I’ll get me a ruddy good telling off!",
                    "Persian": "باید به طور بی‌سیم شارژش کنید اما خوشبختانه می‌شه توی ماشین لباسشویی شستش."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "So around this suit are various sensors that are analysing my motion and the idea is that they’ll be able to tell me if I’m using the correct posture or not when doing various exercises. So if I’m not doing my lunges correctly I’ll get me a ruddy good telling off!",
                    "Persian": "آئودی با ایده‌ای اومده که قراره ما رو در حین ماشین‌سواری و در صندلی پشتی ماشین سرگرم کنه. بعدا نگاهی بهش می‌اندازم."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "DAVE: “How are we doing?”",
                    "Persian": "آئودی با ایده‌ای اومده که قراره ما رو در حین ماشین‌سواری و در صندلی پشتی ماشین سرگرم کنه. بعدا نگاهی بهش می‌اندازم."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "Woman: “Alright. Enjoy the ride”",
                    "Persian": "آئودی با ایده‌ای اومده که قراره ما رو در حین ماشین‌سواری و در صندلی پشتی ماشین سرگرم کنه. بعدا نگاهی بهش می‌اندازم."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "DAVE: “Brilliant”",
                    "Persian": "آئودی با ایده‌ای اومده که قراره ما رو در حین ماشین‌سواری و در صندلی پشتی ماشین سرگرم کنه. بعدا نگاهی بهش می‌اندازم."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "GFX: 5 - 5",
                    "Persian": "آئودی با ایده‌ای اومده که قراره ما رو در حین ماشین‌سواری و در صندلی پشتی ماشین سرگرم کنه. بعدا نگاهی بهش می‌اندازم."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "GFX: 5 - 5",
                    "Persian": "آئودی با ایده‌ای اومده که قراره ما رو در حین ماشین‌سواری و در صندلی پشتی ماشین سرگرم کنه. بعدا نگاهی بهش می‌اندازم."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "GFX: 5 - 5",
                    "Persian": "آئودی با ایده‌ای اومده که قراره ما رو در حین ماشین‌سواری و در صندلی پشتی ماشین سرگرم کنه. بعدا نگاهی بهش می‌اندازم."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "GFX: 5 - 5",
                    "Persian": "خب وقتی به راهش می‌اندازم واقعا حسش می‌کنم چون خودروی واقعی حرکت می‌کنه."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": "GFX: 5 - 5",
                    "Persian": "نیل والنی: "
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": " ",
                    "Persian": "نیل والنی: "
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": " ",
                    "Persian": "نیل والنی: "
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "OOV:",
                    "English": " ",
                    "Persian": "نیل والنی: "
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "OOV:",
                    "English": " ",
                    "Persian": "نمی‌دونم اما مجموع واقعیت مجازی و دور دور زدن توی پیست مسابقه حس و حال خوبی بهم نداد."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": " ",
                    "Persian": "نمی‌دونم اما مجموع واقعیت مجازی و دور دور زدن توی پیست مسابقه حس و حال خوبی بهم نداد."
                },
                null,
                {
                    "Meta": "PTC:",
                    "English": " ",
                    "Persian": "گفتی که حالم رو بد نمی‌کنه اما دروغ بود."
                },
             
                }
            ]
        }
```

And finally, here is the input dirty json:

```
[
  "FARSI 975 CES 2019 ",
  "",
  "",
  "SPEN / CES SETUP",
  "",
  "",
  "PIX - CES",
  "",
  "OOV:",
  "2019 starts with the Consumer Electronics Show in Las Vegas",
  "This is where you come to see all the big new tech - the crazy new ideas, and the occasional polar bear. (PIX- polar bear) Anything to get attention, basically - which is Vegas all over.",
  "",
  "سال ۲۰۱۹ با نمایشگاه بین‌المللی سی ای اس در لاس‌وگاس آغاز شد",
  "جایی که همه میان تا بزرگ‌ترین فناوری‌های تازه، ایده‌های جدید دیوانه‌وار و حتی خرس‌های قطبی رو ببینند. ",
  "و هر چه که توجه‌ها رو به خودش جلب کنه... چیزی که اصلا ماهیت وگاسه.",
  "OOV:",
  "But what does it all mean? What will the coming year look like? What is the important tech that you need to look out for?",
  "",
  "ولی همه اینها به چه معناست؟ سال  میلادی پیش رو چه طور خواهد بود؟ و مهم‌ترین فناوری‌هایی که قراره دنبالش بریم چه چیزهاییه؟",
  "",
  "",
  "PTC:",
  "We’re going and try to tell you the story of CES 2019 by bringing you... ",
  "",
  "ما تلاش می کنیم چند و چون نمایشگاه سی ای اس 2019 را با شما در میان بذاریم با...\u2028",
  "GFX - COUNTERS APPEAR FOR 20 GADGETS AND 19 - LET’S MAKE THEM SAY 20 AND 19 AT FIRST",
  "",
  "PTC:",
  "...20 bits of tech in the next 19 minutes - mind you, that is a lot of stuff in not a lot of time, we better crack on. Quick tip, CES is always a mix of big trends and stuff and nonsense - I will leave you to workout which is which...",
  "",
  "بیست تکه فناوری در 19 دقیقه. دقت کنید که این چیزای خیلی زیادیه در وقت خیلی کم.",
  "بهتره شروع کنیم. یک نکته این که سی ای اس همیشه تلفیقی از فناوری های گنده و چیزهای بی معنیه، قضاوتش با شما.",
  "",
  "GFX - REWIND THE COUNTERS FROM 20 TO 0 AND FROM 19 TO 0",
  "",
  "PTC changed to OOV:",
  "So, reset the counter, reset the clock - and we’ll start with something that’s always big here - TVs…",
  "",
  "خب، از محصولات بزرگ این نمایشگاه شروع می‌کنیم، یعنی تلویزیون‌ها",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "SPEN / GADGET 1 / OLED LG TV",
  "",
  "",
  "PIX ROSE DISPLAY 4 CURVED PRETTY DISPLAYS ",
  "",
  "OOV:",
  "The big screen technology here is OLED, and LG Display is the only company making large OLED screens. The tech has several advantages. It can be curved. It can do really black blacks... ",
  "",
  "فناوری بزرگ نمایشگر در اینجا او لده، و ال‌جی دیسپلی تنها شرکتیه که نمایشگرهای بزرگ او-لد می‌سازه. فناوری‌ای که چندین قابلیت داره. می‌تونه قوس برداره، می‌تونه سیاهش واقعا سیاه سیاه باشه...",
  ""
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's relevant, but what  are OOV or PIX?

Comment: My second question is just clarification on your parsing function. You're taking 3 elements of the Array and those are always `meta`, `english`, and `persian` in that order? In your dirty input it doesn't seem that way. I do see a `RegExp` switch system, but I'm not understanding how you're separating these exactly?

Comment: OOV means Out of View and PIX just means pictures. Yes, you're right that the order isn't always meta, English and Persian - the order is sometimes meta, meta, meta, English, Persian, Persian for example. Thus leading me to problems in parsing it. I'm using regex to break up what is meta 'by having OOV', what is English 'by not being OOV and being English characters', and what is Persian 'by not being an English character'. This is the only way I can see of splitting them up but perhaps there is a better way. Also, my looping through causes repetitions every time as I need to read line by line

Comment: okay thanks for responding,  I'll take a look when I get a chance

Comment: I think you will probably get a better response if you ask 3 separate questions. For each one, supply a minimal example that shows the problem.